# SQL Sum of different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hi i need some help in making query to SUM different Materials in one.

MaterialName Quantity Date
A ...................... 20 .... 1/1/2010
A ...................... 10 .... 1/2/2010
B ...................... 30 .... 1/2/2010
C ...................... 20 .... 1/3/2010

for example I only want to sum Material A and B.

Comment: before asking question, do some research...this is sql basics...just you need google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Add a `where clause` to filter `A` & `B` then `SUM` the quantity per `MaterialName`

```
SELECT MaterialName,
       Sum(Quantity) Sum_Quantity
FROM   TableName
WHERE  MaterialName IN ( 'A', 'B' )
GROUP  BY MaterialName
```

Comment: thank you. how about if i also make sum of material C?

Comment: @Ralph Remove `Where clause`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM TABLE WHERE MaterialName in ('A', 'B')
```

OR

```
SELECT MaterialName , SUM(Quantity) FROM TABLE 
WHERE MaterialName in ('A', 'B') GROUP BY MaterialName
```

Answer (score 0):

Count of A,B

```
select sum(case when MaterialName='A' then 1 else 0 end) as CountA,
sum(case when MaterialName='B' then 1 else 0 end) as CountB,
GROUP BY Date
```

if you mean sum of Quantity

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity),MaterialName  FROM TABLE WHERE MaterialName in ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY MaterialName
```